# Using q.js, does q.all execute immediate functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, q

Working with q.all, it seems the immediate functions in my array are not executing.  The functions should each create a resolved promise, print it to console, and then return it.  I'm seeing no console output, but Q.all seems satisfied and triggers 'then' with 2 null values.  What's wrong with this?  Thanks!

```
var Q = require("q");
var p = Q('Q');
console.log('hi p='+ JSON.stringify(p.inspect()));
return Q.all([
    function(){
        var a = Q('A');
        console.log('thing A: '+JSON.stringify(a.inspect()));
        return a;
    },
    function(){
        var b= Q('B');
        console.log('thing B: '+JSON.stringify(b.inspect()));
        return b;
    }
]).then(
    function(r){
        console.log('A and B are done: '+JSON.stringify(r));
    }
)
```

Comment: To my understanding `all` should be given an array of promises, not functions. https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination

Answer (score 2):

> with q.all, it seems the immediate functions in my array are not executing

Yes. [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) does not expect an array of functions, but an *array of promises*!

You are supposed to execute them yourself, `Q.all` does not need to (should not) know where the *promises* are coming from. They might not be created on the fly every time, some applications use promises that have been created long times ago.

> but `Q.all` seems satisfied and triggers 'then' with 2 null values

Not exactly. `Q.all` does not only take promises in that array, but also arbitrary values, which are automatically wrapped in promises. That means your code is equal to putting two promises that resolve with functions as their result values, which are passed in the `r` array to your callback then. It's `JSON.stringify()` that yields null values, they're functions actually. Do `console.log('A and B are done', r)` instead.